# Handling a variable but bounded number of arguments

Tags: python, exception

Here is the code I was using:

```
def arithmetic_arranger(eq1 = '', eq2 = '', eq3 = '', eq4 = '', eq5 = '', answers = False):
try:
    print(eq1 + eq2 + eq3 + eq4 + eq5)
except TypeError:
    raise('Does not work')

arithmetic_arranger('hello', 'hola', 'konnichiwa', 'bonjour', 'hi', 'hey', 'sup')
```

I want to call the function, and if there are more than 5 arguments (excluding variables) then it should return (for my purposes) 'Does not work'. This is my first time dealing with exceptions, and I cannot seem to figure out how to deal with it coming from inside the function.

Tried:

```
def arithmetic_arranger(eq1 = '', eq2 = '', eq3 = '', eq4 = '', eq5 = '', answers = False):

try:
print(eq1 + eq2 + eq3 + eq4 + eq5)
except TypeError:
raise('Does not work')
arithmetic_arranger('hello', 'hola', 'konnichiwa', 'bonjour', 'hi', 'hey', 'sup')
```

Got:

```
TypeError: arithmetic_arranger() takes from 0 to 6 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

Expecting:

```
Does not work
```

Comment: Could you fix the indentation on your code?

Comment: I believe the error is being thrown when you are calling the function, not from within the function itself, so the catch is not catching the error. Have you considered passing in the parameters as an array instead and then checking the length?

Comment: `raise("Does not work")` what do you expect that to do? `raise` require an Exception object, so that itself will cause a type error. Did you mean `return "does not work"`? Although, returning that is probably not a good idea

Comment: In any case, the error isn't arising from within the function, it is coming from the function call, the function never gets executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*args` to get a list of arguments, then check the length to see if it is > 5:

```py
def arithmetic_arranger(*args, answers=False):
    if len(args) > 5:
        return "does not work"
```

```
# First is fine
>>> arithmetic_arranger('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
# Second has 6 args; will not work
>>> arithmetic_arranger('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6')
'does not work'
# This is still 6 args; will not work
>>> arithmetic_arranger('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', True)
'does not work'
# This will work because you specified that the last arg is answers; not in *args
>>> arithmetic_arranger('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', answers=True)
```

---

Note the use of `return`, which sends the caller a value. I think you may have mistaken `return` for `raise()`?

> [A good read on `*args` and `**kwargs`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*args` to handle a variable number of parameters, and then use `' '.join()` in the print statement to handle cases when less than 5 parameters are passed in:

```py
def arithmetic_arranger(*args):
    if len(args) > 5:
        raise TypeError('Can specify at most five arguments to arithmetic_arranger()')
    print(' '.join(args))
```